# The problem that MRTK's IInputClickHandler method is called repeatedly

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I am developing the HoloLens app using Unity2018.3.1 and MRTKver.2017.4.2

At first, I could use MRTK exsamples' script "Interactive.sc" etc. without problem in AirTap series operation, but OnInputClicked (InputClickedEventData ecentData) of IInputClickHandler came to be called twice by AirTap once at a time .

I'm wondering if MRTK should be reintroduced or the code should be reviewed and rewritten

Comment: Do you maybe have multiple objects parented with the script attached? That might cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if `InteractionInputSource.GestureRecognizer_Tapped()` is called more than once for each air tap?